# Stuck trying to use dropzone gem on rails for multiple upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js

I have 1 form which use dropzone gem, what i am trying to achieve is
i want to upload my image inside a form which have 1 to many relationship, i've been struggle to make it work with no luck.

here is my database structure :

apartement:

```
id
name
desc
```

unitplan:

```
   id
    unitplanphoto
    apartement_id
```

an apartement has many unit plans, instead an unit plan only belong to 1 apartement,

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="animated fadeIn">

          <!--/.row-->
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header">
                          <strong>Apartement Form</strong>
                      </div>

                      <%= form_for @apt, html: {class: "form-horizontal", :multipart=>true} do |f| %>

                        <div class="card-block">

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Apartement Name', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         <%= f.text_field :apt_name, class: "form-control" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Apartement Address', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                           <%= f.text_area :apt_address, rows: 5, cols: 46 , class: "form-control" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Latitude', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         <%= f.text_field :apt_lat, class: "form-control" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Longtitude', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         <%= f.text_field :apt_long, class: "form-control" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Thumbnail', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         <%= f.file_field :thumbnail, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                               <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Appartement Description', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                         <%= f.text_area :apt_desc, rows: 5, cols: 46 , class: "form-control" %>

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                               <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Developer', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">

                                            <%= collection_select(:apt, :developer_id, @developers, :id, :devname, {:prompt => false},  class: "form-control") %> 

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Area', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">

                                            <%= collection_select(:apt, :area_id, @areas, :id, :area_desc, {:prompt => false},  class: "form-control") %> 

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Status', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                           <%= f.select :apt_status, options_for_select(@apt_statuses.collect { |s| [s[0].humanize, s[0]] }, selected: @apt.apt_status), {} , class: "form-control" %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Facility', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">



                                      <%= collection_check_boxes(:apt, :facility_ids, @facilities, :id, :facility_desc) %>  


                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Point of Interest', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">




                                          <%= collection_check_boxes(:apt, :poi_ids, @pois, :id, :poi_name) %>  

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 <div class="form-group row">

                                    <%= f.label 'Floor plan photos', class: 'col-md-4 form-control-label' %>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">






                                               <%= file_field_tag "images[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>




                                    </div>
                                </div>
                      <% end %>


                        <div class="form-group row">



                                    <div class="col-md-8">

                                            <input id="unitplans_ids" name="unitplans_ids" type="hidden" value="">
                                            <!--<input data-url="/photos" id="unitplans_upload" multiple="multiple" name="unitplans[]" type="file" ></input>-->
                                            <!--<form action="/unitplans/create" id="dzCover" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">-->
                                            <%= form_for @unitplan, html: {class: "dropzone", :multipart=>true, id: "dzCover"} do |f| %>
                                                <div id="actionsCover" class="row">

                                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                        <label for="image">Unit plan photos : </label>
                                                        <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                                                        <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button2">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                                                            <span>Add files...</span>
                                                        </span>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                                                            <span>Start upload</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                                                            <span>Cancel upload</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                                                        <!-- The global file processing state -->
                                                        <span class="fileupload-process">
                                                        <div id="total-progress" class="progress progress-striped active" style="display:none" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                                                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>

                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <!-- HTML heavily inspired by http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ -->
                                                        <div class="table table-striped" class="files" id="previewsCover">

                                                            <div id="templateCover" class="file-row">
                                                                <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <span class="preview"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></span>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <p class="name" data-dz-name></p>
                                                                    <strong class="error text-danger" data-dz-errormessage></strong>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                    <p class="size" data-dz-size></p>
                                                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0">
                                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start">
                                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                                                                    <span>Start</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <button type="button" data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                                                                    <span>Cancel</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                <button type="button" data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
                                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                                                                    <span>Delete</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <br>
                                                    </div>
                                           <!-- </form>-->
                                           <% end %>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit</button>


                        </div>
                  </div>

              </div>

              <!--/col-->
          </div>
          <!--/.row-->


      </div>
  </div>
```

my js file :

```
$( document ).ready(function()
{
     var previewNode1 = document.querySelector("#templateCover");

    console.log(previewNode1);
    console.log(previewNode1.id);

    previewNode1.id = "";
    var previewTemplate1 = previewNode1.parentNode.innerHTML;
    previewNode1.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode1);

    var myDropzoneCover = new Dropzone("#dzCover", { // Make the whole body a dropzone
    url: "/unitplans/create", // Set the url
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    paramName: "unitplanphoto",
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate1,
    autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    previewsContainer: "#previewsCover", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button2", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    maxFilesize: 5,
    acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpg, .jpeg", //is this correct? I got an error if im using this
    init: function() {
                            this.on("success", function(file, response)
                            {
                                console.log(response);
                                file.serverId = response;
                                //alert(response);
                            });
                            this.on("removedfile", function(file)
                            {

                            //console.log(file);
                            //console.log(file.serverId);

                                if (!file.serverId)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                    $.post("/unitplans/destroy?id=" + file.serverId);

                            });
                            this.options.previewaDropzone = false;
                        }
    });

    myDropzoneCover.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    // Hookup the start button
    file.previewElement.querySelector("#previewsCover .start").onclick = function() { myDropzoneCover.enqueueFile(file); };

    //console.log(file);
    });

    // Update the total progress bar
    myDropzoneCover.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
    document.querySelector("#actionsCover #total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
    });

    myDropzoneCover.on("sending", function(file) {
    // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
    document.querySelector("#actionsCover #total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
    // And disable the start button
    file.previewElement.querySelector("#previewsCover .start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    //alert("sending");
    });

    // Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
    myDropzoneCover.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
    document.querySelector("#actionsCover #total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
    //alert("complete");
    });

    // Setup the buttons for all transfers
    // The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
    // `clickable` has already been specified.
    document.querySelector("#actionsCover .start").onclick = function() {
    myDropzoneCover.enqueueFiles(myDropzoneCover.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
    };
    document.querySelector("#actionsCover .cancel").onclick = function() {
    myDropzoneCover.removeAllFiles(true);
    };
} );
```

controller file:

```
class UnitplansController < ApplicationController

     def create
        @unitplan = Unitplan.new(unitplan_params)

        #respond_to do |format|
            if @unitplan.save
                render json: {message: "sukses", unitplanID: @unitplan.id}, status: 200
            else
                render json: { error: @unitplan.errors.full_messages.join(", ") }, status: 400
            end
        end



     private
     def unitplan_params
        params.require(:unitplan).permit(:unitplanphoto)
     end

end
```

somehow i can not make it to work,if i check dropzone request when i click submit, it always throw this error :

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UnitplansController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: unitplan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `params` appear to be missing the `unitplan` key that your `unitplan_params` method is looking for.

Try changing your `paramName`value in your js file to this:

```
paramName: "unitplan[unitplanphoto]",
```

`unitplan_params` is acting as a whitelist for params to ensure you only pass approved params to your controller method, so you need to make sure your incoming params match the `require` and `permit` rules.

Comment: I am trying to upload more than 5 images on Amazone s3 at a time and my AJAX code is in the success block which updates a div with uploaded files. What happens if I select 4 images and upload, it is working. But if I upload more than 4 images, it's uploading but not getting the callback in success block. Do you know why?